# Trim a char array

Tags: c#, arrays

Background: I was invited to an interview at a high profile company and I was asked the following question before being told I failed the interview for the position (C#,mvc3,razor). **I'm genuinely interested in how to solve this.**

Question: `"Write a method that takes a char array, trims whitespace, and returns the same array."` After some thinking I was told to replace the whitespace with "\o".

I started with:

```
public static char[] Trim(char[] c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        {
            if (c[i] == '\r' || c[i] == '\n' || c[i] == '\t')
            {
                c[i] = '\o';
            }     
        }
    }
```

I was told I have to use the same array, can't put it in a list and call `ToArray()`. However I think if the array stays the same size it is impossible to "trim it".

Comment: This sounds like a badly worded question... some interviewers ask them on purpose to see if you're willing to ask questions.  Just a little interviewing tip.  When I interviewed with Amazon, they changed their minds several times just to see if I'd get pissed off.

Comment: Well, don't get down.  On multiple levels, this seems like a terrible interview question to me.  (1. Contrived and ridiculous to consume/return the same character array  2. Silly to use a character array in the first place  3. Trying to shoehorn the ideas of null-terminated strings in C# is just obnoxious 4. It's not much of a problem to solve at all; just a "gotcha" question trying to trap you.)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I agree -the wording is strange enough that I'm guessing the goal was to get the interviewee to ask questions and talk about the problem.  Bringing up issues to get to the real problem "behind" the question might have been the goal here, not a code solution...

Comment: @KirkWoll: Strings represented as character arrays are mutable, whereas System.String is immutable, so they have their uses.

Comment: @KirkWoll yes, the fact that they were asking you to handle null-terminated strings in C# makes no sense.  If it was a C/C++ position, it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I can agree that he might have wanted to see what questions I asked. And believe me, I did, which seemed to anger him more. I'm not mad that I was asked that question, I'm wondering why I passed the HR and technical call, was asked to come out for an interview only to be told I was rejected after one question.

Comment: ...they seriously rejected you for not answering this badly worded question?  You probably didn't want to work for them, you'd have a head full of grey hair in six months.

Comment: @David, that distinction is totally irrelevant in practice, as re-assigning string variables to new values is all one ever really wants.

Comment: If you didn't recognize the difference between \0 and \O, that could have very well been the deal killer.  While it might not have been a "fair" assessment of your overall knowledge and experience, you have to appreciate him not wasting any more of your (or his) time once had set `hire` to false.

Comment: I see your problem. You didn't make it go FizzBuzz at the right time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they meant to replace whitespace characters with null characters then the solution is simple:

Step 1: From the start of the string (represented as a character array) replace whitespace characters until a non-WS character is encountered.

Step 2: From the end of the string, working backwards, do the same.

```cs
public static void Trim( Char[] chars )
{        
    int maxIdx = 0; // an optimization so it doesn't iterate through chars already encountered
    for( int i = 0;i < chars.Length; i++ )
    {
        if( Char.IsWhitespace( chars[i] ) )
        {
            chars[i] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            maxIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for( int i = chars.Length - 1; i > maxIdx; i-- )
    {
        if( Char.IsWhitespace( chars[i] ) ) chars[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: David, I forgot to mention that I also have to move all of the '\o' characters to the very end.

Answer (score 6):

They may have meant \0 (NUL character), not dash-0

Answer (score 2):

```
public static char[] Trim(char[] str)
{
  return str.Where(x => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but this would internally create a new character array with no whitespace characters.

Comment: Yes - but answers the question. The example they gave you doesn't trim the whitespace, it sets the char to null character.

Comment: The question states I cannot return a new array, it has to be the same one.

Comment: Lol - I would have been booted as well then ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly and untested, but it does the whole thing in a single pass without creating a new array:

```
public static void Trim(Char[] str) {

    int nonNullIndex = 0;
    int lastNonNullIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<str.Length;i++) {
        str[nonNullIndex] = str[i];
        if( !Char.IsWhitespace( str[i] ) || nonNullIndex > 0) nonNullIndex++;
        if( !Char.IsWhitespace( str[i] )) lastNonNullIndex = i;
    }
    nonNullIndex++
    str[lastNonNullIndex] = '\0';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you might have been asked is to remove white space from between the string and then fill the char array for the remaining elements of the array with '\0'

e.g. "Convert this string" to "Convertthisstring" and fill the remaining array with 2 '\0'

Solution:

```
    char[] TrimWhiteSpace(char[] source)
    {
        int i, j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(source[i]))
            {
                source[j] = source[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < (i - j); x++)
        {
            source[j + x] = '\0';
        }

        return source;
    }
```